# How to check how many Oracle user sessions are running

Tags: users, oracle-database

I need to check how many users are connected to server for specific applications through a browser. I'm mainly interested in Oracle. My server runs RHEL.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected through browser"? HTTP is a stateless protocol, so to know how many users are connected is server application thing? To list users logged in, use `users` or `who`.

Comment: Ok We have oracle Application installed on our server. So is it possible to check how many sessions are running and will it be possible to check for http also?

Comment: no unless the application reports the statistics somewhere you can access them (or you would have to analyze the packets belonging to the application and deduct from those). Check the application's documentation on how to get that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it possible to check how many sessions are running and will it be possible to check for http also?

A web application needs to be configured or programmed to enumerate active sessions, but for a list of users and idle times for SSH sessions...

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1,5 | tail -n +3
```

See the NOTES section in the man page for w. The line above produces something like this:

```
username1 0.00s
username2 48.08s
```

Or, only idle times:

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 5 | tail -n +3
```

Or, just a count of SSH sessions:

```
 w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 5 | tail -n +3 | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

The command `who` tells you which users are logged in on which terminals. Read `man who` for more details about logged-in users.